# How to remove function defs from RStudio's code outline for more clarity?

Tags: r, rstudio

In RStudio, I use the `####` tags to structure my code and have a neat and tidy code outline (see below). However, I would like the functions (`foo` etc.) sometimes not be shown in the outline as it often makes the structure too confusing and untidy (red arrows), especially when the file is big and contains many functions defs.

**Is there a way to suppress (or toggle) showing the functions in the code outline?**

**.. or to set the indentation level of the function entries so they become less prominent in the code outline?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to source a second script that holds all relevant functions and source that at the start of your original file.